# using ScaleBy method for TMonthCalendar

Tags: delphi, scale, monthcalendar

I'm using ScaleBy method to scale up/down Forms of my application at run-time. it works for almost all components but not for TMonthCalendar.
Is there a way to enlarge TMonthCalendar using ScaleBy or any other method?

Comment: The v6 control regards font size of visual styles. Try calling SetWindowTheme(MonthCalendarHandle, '', '') to have the v5 control before attempting to scale.

Comment: eg: `ScaleBy(200, 100);` `MonthCalendar1.RecreateWnd;` `SetWindowTheme(MonthCalendar1.Handle, '', '');`

Comment: Hey @Sertac, your answer was very helpful. I had tried disabling theme but it was not working. Also MonthCalendar doesn't RecreatWnd. meybe it is protected. Anyway I found the solurion and will post it as answer however I loose the visual style but better than nothing! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Indeed, it would require some hack to access the protected RecreateWnd method, your solution is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it works on;y if you disable theme. you also need to make a size change to make it work

```
SetWindowTheme(MonthCalendar1.Handle, '', '');
MonthCalendar1.ScaleBy(190, 100);
MonthCalendar1.Width := MonthCalendar1.Width + 1;
MonthCalendar1.Width := MonthCalendar1.Width - 1;
```

Thanks to @Sertac for hints

Answer (score 0):

The MonthCalendar control has a fixed size , you can not change this size ..
the low width size is definded as 225 px and the High width is definded as 450 px .

Comment: `TMonthCalendar` is a wrapper for [`Month Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760917(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows control and it depends on the system which size will it have.

Comment: Yes i think that's true , I mentioned the values obtained from my system .